# Put a value comes from a file in a global variable (AWK script)

Tags: bash, variables, awk, gawk

I have several files (.csv) in entry of my script awk. I separate these files in other files (.csv) that i insert the data of these files into a database with help of a sql loader (oracle).

I want to put a value in the file to put in a global variable which I can use everywhere in `my awk script`.

Do you have ideas how I can create a global variable with in an `AWK script`.

Thank you in advance

Example : `file.csv`

```
NUMBER1;TEXT1;DATE1
NUMBER2;TEXT2;DATE1
NUMBER3;TEXT3;DATE1
NUMBER4;TEXT4;DATE1
NUMBER5;TEXT5;
```

I want to create a new file (`result.csv`) with these informations

```
NUMBER1;DATE1
NUMBER2;DATE1
NUMBER3;DATE1
NUMBER4;DATE1
NUMBER5;DATE1
```

Comment: The global value is DATE1 in my example

Comment: No. i have more processings to be made with the value that i want to put in a global variable. It's a little complicated to all processings in one post but i know how i can make it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. To declare a variable and use it anywhere in awk you can use `BEGIN{ myvar="value" }` and then use `myvar` as global value inside your awk script.

Comment: i did this : globalvar = $Number of the column in the first line that i want to put in my global variable but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do more clearly; at the moment, people are just guessing what you want.

Comment: @Tom Fenech : i think that some people understand (for example mikeb), sorry if it's not very very clear and i think also that it's not possible what i want to do. I am going to try to make it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is what you are trying to do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR==1{date=$NF} {print $1,date}' file
NUMBER1;DATE1
NUMBER2;DATE1
NUMBER3;DATE1
NUMBER4;DATE1
NUMBER5;DATE1
```

Get the book "Effective Awk Programming", 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

Look into BEGIN and END for awk:

`awk 'BEGIN { globalvar = "x" } {} '`

The begin block gets executed once, so set your variable there.

See here: http://code.linuxnix.com/2013/02/awk-scripting-10-begin-and-end-block-examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i did this : globalvar = $Number of the column in the first line that i want to put in my global variable but it doesn't work

Comment: Right, BEGIN happens *before* the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can define variables for your awk script with `-v` option.  For example, assume you have the env variable $DATE.

```
$ DATE=$(date)
$ awk -v date="$DATE" '{print date}' <<< "ignore"
Mon Sep 14 10:27:59 EDT 2015
```

Since your example file.csv already has all the fields I'm not sure what variable you want to pass to the script.  However, assuming that you want the first field from file.csv and generate result.csv with a date variable you can do this

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" -v date="$DATE" '{print $1, date}' file.csv > result.csv
```